# Corrupt data in VS2017 profiler report

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis, profiler

I'm using the profiler in Visual Studio 2017 to profile a .NET C# web application (in my local machine). Lately, when I use the profiler and try to open the generated report, I get this error message in a popup window:

`VSP1738: Corrupt data block found during analysis and data has been truncated.`

Meanwhile in the output window I get a bunch of VSP2701 warnings similar to the following one:
`Warning VSP2701: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MY_PROJECT\29b20858\c4621ca8\assembly\dl3\efbea056\07e7ed64_c0f8d301\RANDOM_DLL_FILE.dll could not be found when looking for symbol information.`

I tried the trivial tricks like restarting VS, recycling the app pools in IIS, deleting the .psess files, recompiling everything and stuff like that. I keep getting those errors.

Comment: « Received »? From another machine?

Comment: @LexLi From my local machine

Comment: Had the same issue today... did you find a solution?
Thanks!